# entry.getAuthor().getGroups() always return empty array

Tags: user-groups, usermodel

I'm trying to output users groups for every entries in a for loop, but it returns an empty array:

```
{%for entry in craft.entries.section('news') %}
    ...
    {{ dump(entry.getAuthor().getGroups()) }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it's working correctly in the entry page itself.

Any idea how I can return the groups in a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

I spot a couple of Twig errors in your code.

First, in your `for` loop you're casting the entries returned by `craft.entries` to a variable `news`, but you're calling `entry.getAuthor()` inside the loop. Either change `news` to `entry` or `entry` to `news`.

Second, I'm not sure if `craft.entries('news')` actually returns anything (or at least not what you actually want) – it should probably be `craft.entries.section('news')`.

Putting it together, this should work:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news') %}
    ...
    {{ dump(entry.getAuthor().getGroups()) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, since you're not reporting any error messages output by Craft, I'm guessing you haven't enabled [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) in your development environment. It's a really good idea to have `devMode` set to `true` while you're working on your code, because then Craft will report any syntax errors (like your undeclared `entry` variable) which will make it way easier for you to debug.

Just remember to never have `devMode` enabled for production environments – it's both a performance and security issue if you do.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the example (the code is a bit more complex than that). So yes craft.entries.section('news') is the correct code I use for that loop, that why I don't have any error...

Comment: Ok, make sure you have `{% for entry...` and not `{% for news...` as well, and your code should be legit. In which case, there are only two reasons I can think of that could cause `entry.getAuthor().getGroups()` to not return anything: 1. Singles doesn't have authors, so if the `news` section is a Single, that'd be the issue. 2. Obviously, `getGroups()` will return an empty array for users who aren't actually in any groups. Are you absolute sure your entry author(s) are assigned to 1 or more groups?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the `news` vs. `entry` issue isn't a typo at all like I thought, but that the `entry` variable is really unrelated to the loop and declared outside it. Is `entry` a Single? If not, can you confirm that its author is a member of one or more user groups?

Comment: Ops sorry I have edited it too fast. Actuality, I think I have found the issue. The list is paginated, and it looks like paginated entries are not returning the entire Entry Model for some reason.